# React is not displaying data from express backend

Tags: reactjs, express

I am trying to get data from a postgres database and display that in a table.

server.js

```js
require("dotenv").config();
const cors = require("cors")
const db = require("./db");
// Express Application setup
const express = require("express");
const morgan = require("morgan");
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const port = process.env.PORT;
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server is UP and running and listening on port ${port}`);
})



app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());


// HTTP request logger middleware
app.use(morgan("dev"));

// Get All Monsters
app.get('/monsters', async  (req, res) => {
    
    const results = await db.query(`select * from monsters`, (err, results) => {
        if (!err) {
            console.log(results)
            res.send(results.rows);
        }
    });
    db.end;
})
```

the server is on port 3100, and when I visit http://localhost:3100/monsters I get a good result:

[{"id":1,"image":{"type":"Buffer","data":[105,109,103,49,46,106,112,103]},"table":null,"cr":"1/2","source":"Monster Manual","type":"Humanoid","size":"Medium","alignment":"N","tags":null,"info":null,"name":"Goblin"},{"id":13,"image":null,"table":null,"cr":"1/4","source":"Monster Manual","type":"Monster","size":"Medium","alignment":"N","tags":null,"info":null,"name":"Spiderz"}]

Also works fine from Postman. The only thing I see in difference that when I run GET in Postman Morgan shows me  **GET /monsters 200 41.481 ms**  , and from the website it shows me: **GET /monsters 304 3.514 ms**.

The problem seems to sit somewhere in the frontend (react).

**App.js:**

```js
import './App.css';
import MainComponent from './components/MainComponent';
import Info from './components/Info';
import Rules from './components/Rules';
import Rulebooks from './components/Rulebooks';
import Monsters from './components/Monsters';
import Adventures from './components/Adventures';
import Contact from './components/Contact';
import { Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import MonsterInfo from './components/MonsterInfo';
import { MonsterContextProvider } from './context/MonsterContext';


function App() {
  return (
    <MonsterContextProvider>
      <div>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<MainComponent />} />
          <Route path="/info" element={<Info />} />
          <Route path="/rules" element={<Rules />} />
          <Route path="/rulebooks" element={<Rulebooks />} />
          <Route path="/monsters" element={<Monsters />} />
          {/* <Route path="/monsters/:id" element={<MonsterInfo />} /> */}
          <Route path="/adventures" element={<Adventures />} />
          <Route path="/contact" element={<Contact />} />
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </MonsterContextProvider>
   
  )
  };

export default App;
```

**context:** MonsterContext.js

```js
import React, { useState, createContext } from "react";

export const MonsterContext = createContext();

export const MonsterContextProvider = props => {
    const [monsters, setMonsters] = useState([])

    // const addMonsters = (monsters) => {
    //     setMonsters([...monsters, monsters]);
    // }
    return (
        <MonsterContext.Provider value={{ monsters: monsters, setMonsters }}>
            {props.children}
        </MonsterContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

**Api:** Monsterfinder.js

```js
import axios from "axios";

export default axios.create({
    baseURL: "http://192.168.0.118:3100/"
});
```

**Page to display data:** MonsterList.jsx

```html
import "./Monsters.css";
import React, { useEffect, useContext } from 'react';
import MonsterFinder from "../apis/MonsterFinder";
import { useNavigate, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { MonsterContext } from '../context/MonsterContext';

const MonsterList = (props) => {
    const { monsters, setMonsters } = useContext(MonsterContext);
    const navigate = useNavigate()

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
        try {
          const response = await MonsterFinder.get("/monsters");
           setMonsters(response.data.data.monsters);
          
        } catch (err) {}
    };
       fetchData();     
    }, []);

    return (
             
        <div className="app-container">
            <h1>Monsters</h1>
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th> </th>
                        <th>Cr</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Source</th>
                        <th>Type</th>
                        <th>Size</th>
                        <th>Alignment</th>
                        <th>Tag</th>
                        <th>Info</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {monsters.map((monster) => {
                        return (
                        <tr>
                            <td><img src={require(`../media/${monster.Image}`)} alt={monster.Name} height="25" width="25" /></td>
                            <td>{monster.Cr}</td>
                            <td>{monster.Name}</td>
                            <td>{monster.Source}</td>
                            <td>{monster.Type}</td>
                            <td>{monster.Size}</td>
                            <td>{monster.Alignment}</td>
                            <td>{monster.Tag}</td>
                            <td><button className="button"><Link className="links" to={`/monsterinfo/${monster.Name}`}>Info</Link></button></td>
                        </tr>
                        );
                    })}
                    
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        
    )
};

export default MonsterList
```

In server.js I console.log(results) And the console shows:

```js
GET /monsters 304 37.024 ms - -
Result {
  command: 'SELECT',
  rowCount: 2,
  oid: null,
  rows: [
    {
      id: 1,
      image: <Buffer 69 6d 67 31 2e 6a 70 67>,
      table: null,
      cr: '1/2',
      source: 'Monster Manual',
      type: 'Humanoid',
      size: 'Medium',
      alignment: 'N',
      tags: null,
      info: null,
      name: 'Goblin'
    },
    {
      id: 13,
      image: null,
      table: null,
      cr: '1/4',
      source: 'Monster Manual',
      type: 'Monster',
      size: 'Medium',
      alignment: 'N',
      tags: null,
      info: null,
      name: 'Spiderz'
    }
  ],
  fields: [
    Field {
      name: 'id',
      tableID: 16391,
      columnID: 1,
      dataTypeID: 23,
      dataTypeSize: 4,
      dataTypeModifier: -1,
      format: 'text'
    },
    
    etc
```

So the data is collected but when I inspect the webpage I see just the thead and get:

[image: Page]

[image: Hooks]

And you see the MonsterList Array=(0)

***The problem is not in how I get the tbody data showing, it worked when I used a mock_data.json file.***

Answer (score 1):

First of all, i'd like to bring your attention to your "useEffect" hook, if you are in [development phase](https://nodejs.dev/fr/learn/nodejs-the-difference-between-development-and-production/), react will mount and unmount your component, making you component render twice, this behavior was implemented to better catch bugs in dev phase. [learn more](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html)

I think you are getting http 304 because your component is fetching the data twice, your endpoint is sending 304 because he is seeing the same payload being requested.

You could use the [useRef](https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/useRef) to solve this exact problem, like so:

```js
// We set a ref to persist a variable between renders
const alreadyRunned = useRef(false)

useEffect(() => {
  if(alreadyRunned.current == false) {
  // We set the "current" property to true, to execute only once the useEffect
  alreadyRunned.current = true;
  
    // Your code here
  }
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining this to me, i tried to implement the useRef, it gives no errors but it doesn't solve the 304, so perhaps i still got some errors: (I also removed <React.StrictMode> from server.js, but it still gives me Get 304.

Comment: Try disabling the browser cache in your browser devtool and see if you still get 304, as a side note look-out for object and array manipulation and react rendering, if the content of the object changes but you are not making a deep-copy of it, the component wont re-render

Shallow vs Deep copy : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-shallow-and-deep-copy-of-a-class/